# ActiveRecord / Arel chain conditions on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'm trying to construct a query that selects a record based on conditions of its associations.
In my example I have `Box has_many Items` and `Item belong_to Box`

I would like to get all `Boxes` which contain `items` with the following conditions:

```
(item.type = "toy" and item.used_count >= 2) AND
(item.type = "book" and item.used_count >= 3) AND
(item.type = "bottle" and item.used_count >= 3)
```

I've tried using Arel, but can't seem to get it right. I can only manage to find Boxes with a single condition, but have been unable to chain them.
Could someone please help me construct this query? I've spent far too long and haven't found any solutions in other SO questions that I could adapt.

Comment: How are you _chaining_ them?

Comment: You surely need to `OR` them together?

Comment: Yes, I probably do need to use `OR` just not sure how to go about doing it. That's exactly my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write this condition in rails you can use `where("SQL directly here")`

like so:

```rb
Box.joins(:items).where("(items.type = 'toy' and items.used_count >= 2) AND (items.type = 'book' and items.used_count >= 3) AND (items.type = 'bottle' and items.used_count >= 3)")
```

note the plural form that indicates the table or association name

**However I don't think this is what you want here**

you want to get the box that has 3 distinct items condition with the first condition (type=toy and used_count>=2) and another item (type=book and used_count>=3) and another_item (type=bottle and used_count>=3)

you might need a custom join here

```rb
Box.joins("JOIN items item1 ON item1.box_id = box.id AND item1.type = 'toy' and item1.user_count >= 2").joins("JOIN items item2 ON item2.box_id = box.id AND item2.type = 'book' and item2.user_count >= 3").joins("JOIN items item3 ON item3.box_id = box.id AND item2.type = 'bottle' and item3.user_count >= 3")
```